# Don't show notifications Android

Tags: java, android, notifications

I'm trying to learn how to develop applications for Android devices. For some time I have been developing an application in which there is a function for sending notifications (reminders) at different times of the day. But if the phone is locked and the time to send the notification is more than 10 minutes then they do not come. Tried BroadcasrReceiver:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    addNotif(context, "Times UP Receiver", "5 second Receiver", "Alert Receiver");
}

private void addNotif(Context context, String msg, String msgText, String msgAlert) {
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent notifIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH).setContentIntent(notifIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp))
            .setTicker(msgAlert)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle(msg)
            .setContentText(msgText);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(101, notification);
}
}
```

use AlarmManager:

```
        Calendar calNotif = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent alertIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 102, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager notifAlarm = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    notifAlarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calNotif.getTimeInMillis() + (15 * 60 * 1000), pendingIntent);
```

I also tried to use Service:

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Calendar calNotif = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent alertIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 103, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager notifAlarm = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    notifAlarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calNotif.getTimeInMillis() + (16 * 60 * 1000), pendingIntent);
    return START_STICKY;
}
}
```

Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".NotificationReceiver" />
    <service android:name=".NotificationService" />
```

But nothing works. My head hurts, I still can not understand why notifications do not come. Tell me please what's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use BaseContext and your going to test notification then why should you delayed 15 mins for notification. Minimize your time and check after its works increase your time.

In YourActivity

```
Calendar calNotif = Calendar.getInstance();
Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 102, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager notifAlarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
notifAlarm.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calNotif.getTimeInMillis()+10000, pendingIntent);
else 
notifAlarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calNotif.getTimeInMillis()+10000, pendingIntent);
```

In your Notification Code

```
 builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH).setContentIntent(notifIntent)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp)
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp))
        .setTicker(msgAlert)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setContentTitle(msg)
        .setContentText(msgText);
```

Remove setLargeIcon beacause it uses Bitmap and takes more memory. After its worked you can implement using service.